VS Code Remote Explorer passing through local git access?
I use the VS Code Remote Explorer and the VS Code terminal to work remotely on an SSH host. On this host, when trying to check out a private Github repository I would expect it to ask for credentials. However it does not, instead it can access the repository. I noticed a .git-credentials is created in my home directory on cloning the private repository.

From inside VS Code Terminal, even after deleting the .git-credentials, I can clone my private repository again - the .git-credentials file is automatically recreated.
Deleting .git-credentials from another SSH client (independent of VS Code) and trying to checkout my private repository in this SSH session fails

So I assume that VS Code somehow passes through some kind of Git access from my desktop computer? How to prevent this as I want to use a personal access token on the remote SSH server?
I am on VS Code 1.95.3. Tried some research on Google but could not find any information on the behaviour I observed.
Update with details about generated .git-credentials:
The .git-credentials that becomes generated contains
https://<8 digits>:gho_<36 characters>@github.com/<github user>/<repository>.git

The first three letters of gho_<36 characters> tell me that it is an OAuth access token according to https://github.blog/engineering/platform-security/behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/
However, GitHub Apps as well as OAuth Apps in my Github Developer Settings are empty.
Installed extensions I have are

Update 2:
In my Github settings -> Applications -> Authorized OAuth Apps I have VS Code listed:

Still wondering if there is any documentation on VS Code "forwarding" a token to a SSH server.
Update 3:
Checked the environment of the VS Code Terminal SSH Session, it contains some stuff about Git, that is not included on a "normal" (e.g. Putty) SSH session:
env|grep -i git
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE
GIT_ASKPASS
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS
VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN

I've removed the values from the output, but VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE sounds interesting, like a connection to the VS Code running on my desktop and having access to my Github. Guess this passes on the token, but as of now that is just an assumption.

Can you describe the content ofthe .git-credentials? Don't send it as obviously it's not something to share but describe it, it could help. Also, having a list of the extensions that you have installed and could be realted could be a good thing.

@foxypiratecove37350 Thanks for asking, I've added requested details to my question

added another about environment variables only set in VS Code ssh session
